# Будет ли страдать время и память, если вызывать недавно созданную переменную?

Tags: c#, оптимизация

Я писал программу для решения следущей задачи (решил её):

*"У нас есть корабли, оснащенные 10-ю пассажирскими капсулами.
В капсулу помещается 10 пассажиров.
В первую экспедицию хотят отправиться n человек.
Первые 10 человек садятся в первую капсулу, вторые 10 человек – во вторую и т.д. Если в итоге останется меньше 10 человек, они грустные уходят домой.
Дальше капсулы присоединяются к кораблям по 10 штук. Если в итоге останется меньше 10 капсул, они остаются на станции.
Улетают только полностью укомплектованные корабли.
Напиши программу, которая посчитает, сколько кораблей улетит, сколько капсул с пассажирами останется на станции и сколько человек уйдет домой.
Формат входных данных
Одно целое число: n – количество пассажиров.
Формат выходных данных
Три целых числа : количество улетевших кораблей, количество оставшихся капсул и количество ушедших домой человек."*

Вот код (на его примере хочу показать, что мне нуно узнать):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace lesson5
{
    class Exercise
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int ships = (n / 10) / 10;
            int capsules = n / 10 % 10;
            int sad_people = n % 10;
            Console.WriteLine($"{ships} {capsules} {sad_people}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Меня интересует следующее: можно ли для присваивания значения новой переменной вызывать предыдущую?

Сейчас покажу, что имею в виду:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace lesson5
{
    class Exercise
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int ships = n / 10 / 10;
            int sad_people = n % 10;
            int happy_people = n - sad_people; //добавим "счастливых людей", что уместились в капсулы, чтоб пример удался
            int gone_capsules = happy_people / 10; // те капсулы, что до присоединения к кораблю
            int remaining_capsules = happy_people / 10 % 10; //всё те же оставшиеся капсулы
            Console.WriteLine($"{ships} {remaining_capsules} {sad_people}");
            Console.WriteLine($"{gone_capsules} {happy_people}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Ведь можно решить всё через `n`, но страдает ли время выполнения кода, количество памяти, выделяемой в стеке, независимость отдельных частей программы, если использовать 2 способ.

Буду рад конструктивной критике и более глобальным примерам. Я ведь только учусь, поэтому мыслю предметно, размышляю над тем, что сейчас вижу перед собой.

Comment: Нужно писать понятный код всегда, а оптимизировать только тогда, когда есть какие-то проблемы производительности. В вашем примере не понадобится оптимизация никогда, во-первых компилятор очень хорошо умеет оптимизировать код, во-вторых даже если вы займете лишние 10 байт в памяти на 0,00001 с, ну кого это волнует?

Comment: Вы не говорите компилятору что делать буквально. Вы говорите компилятору какой вы хотите получить результат. Компилятор создаёт код для получения этого результата, но этот код не обязательно буквальный перевод вашей программы. Это называется оптимизация. Подозреваю, что для обоих программ компилятор создаст один и тот же код в итоге. Не нужно об этом думать пока.

Comment: Компилятор оптимизирует код. Локальная переменная может вообще не занимать память, а жить например в регистре процессора. Пишите в первую очередь понятный и поддерживаемый код. Решайте проблемы производительности тогда, когда они возникают.